# use Kummer discriminance in series to structure a new specific discriminance

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

In series，the *Kummer discriminance* is
if $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{c_n}$$is a convergent positive series.And $$\mathscr K_n=c_n\cdot \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-c_{n+1},$$then if $\exists\mathbb N,\forall n\ge \mathbb N$, 
$\mathscr K_n\ge\delta,$($\delta$ is a positive number),then $\sum a_n$ is convergent.
if $\exists\mathbb N,\forall n\ge \mathbb N$, $\mathscr K_n\le 0$,then$\sum a_n$ is divergent.

I want to know how to use the convergent series $$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\cdot\sqrt[n]{n}}$$ as the above $c_n$ to struct a specific discriminance.Just like use $c_n=1$ to struct the d'Alembert discriminane.